# preg_match_all does not give results

Tags: php, html, regex

I don't know why but when I execute the script it doesn't display the lines correctly. It just gives the last line of the variable lines back with no input under it. Am I overlooking something?

```
<?php
    $stop = '06BAH';
    $input = file_get_contents('File1.txt'); 
    $lines = file('File2.txt'); 

    for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) { 
        preg_match_all("/^($lines[$i].*)$stop/msU", $input, $matches);
    }
?>
```

File1:

```
06BAH  TOI00123-11-134-B                        OP_SIGNAGE                                       10  
05  6       00132-12-172-A                4                                                                                    PON
05  7       00127-22-683-A                3                                                                                   PON
05  9       00927-62-133-A                11                                                                                    PON
05  18      00227-72-542-A                8                                                                                   PON
06BAH   TOI00877-27-836-C                        OP_SIGNAGE                                      10 
05  122     00238-92-963-A                3                                                                                    PON
05  173     00124-65-832-A                2                                                                                    PON
06BAH   TOI00112-54-980-B                        OP_SIGNAGE                                      10
```

File2:

```
TOI00123-11-134-B
TOI00112-54-980-B
```

Output:

```
06BAH   TOI00123-11-134-B                        OP_SIGNAGE                                       10  
05  6       00132-12-172-A                4                                                                                    PON
05  7       00127-22-683-A                3                                                                                   PON
05  9       00927-62-133-A                11                                                                                    PON
05  18      00227-72-542-A                8                                                                                   PON
06BAH   TOI00112-54-980-B                        OP_SIGNAGE                                       10
```

Comment: Can you add file content?

Comment: after `$lines = file('File2.txt'); ` define `$final_data = array();` and then inside `for loop` change `$final_data[] = preg_match_all("/^($lines[$i].*)$stop/msU", $input);` and then after end of loop `var_dump($final_data);`

Comment: im on it :) give me a min to edit it a little

Comment: anant, it gives the exact same problem but it does look better ;)

Comment: Can you give us an example input?

Comment: added some content to the question :)

Comment: `<?php
    $stop = 'key';
    $input = file_get_contents('File1.txt'); 
 echo "<pre/>";print_r($input);
    $lines = file('File2.txt'); 
 echo "<pre/>";print_r($lines);
 $final_data = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) { 
        $final_data[] = preg_match_all("/^($lines[$i].*)$stop/msU", $input);
    }
 echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_data); 
?>`

Comment: @Anant: _**Space for posting answer is below !**_

Comment: Well, you have a loop and you never store results. No wonder you only get the last one...

Comment: `preg_match_all` can perform a global match of file content, you don't need execute it on every line.

Comment: oke but anant, im glad you try to help but it gives the same output as my previous code did... ill edit the question and give the output example :p

Comment: Why are you using preg_match_anything at all ? It looks like your code is tryhing to find the first and last time a marker appears, and dump the lines - you do not need a regex to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, although you are storing results in `$matches` you are overwriting the `$matches` everytime your loop iterates.

You should go along the lines of this:

```
<?php
$stop = '06BAH';
$input = file_get_contents('file1.txt'); 
$lines = file('file2.txt'); 
$caught = []; 

for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) { 
    preg_match_all("/(".trim($lines[$i]).".*)".trim($stop)."/msU", $input, $matches);
    foreach($matches as $key => $value) {
        $caught[$i] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($caught);

?>
```

Also, note the change to your regular expression - I'm not the best with regex but after testing your original expression it wasn't matching with the anchor `^`.

Comment: screen full of errors :D preg_match expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: ehm.. the output is nothing and to be hounest... i dont understand your code.. im kinda new to php though

Comment: I can explain the code to you, happily. I've updated the code in my answer - I've just tested it on my local machine & it outputs what you have posted in your question. What sort of output are you looking for?

Comment: The call to `preg_match` in unnecessary, it's just another function call and nesting level. Showing your output (`$caught`) would probably help the OP - (Expected) Output is in the question.

Comment: Good call on the `preg_match` - I posted in my previous comment that the output is the same to what he has in his question. Which, if the OP wants a different output points to the regular expression. Thanks.

Comment: thats it :) great!